# Custom Rails action and forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm still trying to get my head around actions and routes. I more or less understand how to user forms with the build-in controller actions like create, show, etc. What I want to do for a demo app is imitate a school's class schedule, where I have Courses and Students with a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship.

I'm using Mongoid, and I can add students to a course and vice versa using the console, but I can't figure out how to do it with a form. Would adding students to a course even be a controller action, or can I write and call a setter in the model somehow? If a controller action is better, what would the route look like?

If anyone knows of an example that does something similar, I'd love to examine it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It can be a controller action. If adding students to a course is a simple logic, you could add `/courses/:course_id/Students/add`. This means creating a courses folder, and a students_controller within it, with an add action.

Example (in your routes.rb)

```
resources :courses, :except => [:destroy] do
    resources :students
end
```

More info: https://gist.github.com/jhjguxin/3074080

Is this what you are looking for?